# Docker - cannot move file between volumes from java

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I have two docker containers: producer and consumer.

Consumer container has two volumes:

```
VOLUME      ["/opt/queue/in", "/opt/queue/out"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
consumer:
    image: consumer
producer:
    image: producer
    volumes_from:
    - consumer
```

Producer puts file in `/opt/queue/in` directory and consumer reads file from that dir and moves it to the `/opt/queue/out`. The problem is that consumer is written in Java and following Java code returns `-1` (operation failed).

```
new File('/opt/queue/in/in_file').renameTo(new File('/opt/queue/in/in_file'));
```

When I try to move file from command line there is no error. File is moved correctly. Why this is happening? How can I diagnose what is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The javadoc for File.renameTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) specifically says that it may not be able to move a file between different volumes, and that you should use Files.move if you need to support this case in a platform independent way.

Answer (score 1):

As above mentioned, rename method will not work on docker mount, so You use this copyfile if you are using older version of java like java6. java8 have lots of way to move file

```
try { 
      FileUtils.copyFile(oldfile,newfile);
   } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```